# How to fix " Ignoring file ***** as it has an invalid filename extension"

Tags: command-line, apt, 20.04, package-management, updates

When I try to update my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from terminal I get this error message, any help please?

```
N: Ignoring file 'rethinkdb.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'rethinkdb.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: how about removing them from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: Thank you! I am beginner and I don't know how to do that

Comment: @Rinzwind I have just checked it and there seem to be many options, I am afraid that I chose the wrong one. Could you tell me how to delete them please?

Comment: Mind that that is not the problem you want fixed ;-) It is the "type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.lis" That one is fatal. The other one is ïgnored" so not really an issue.

Comment: Oh, really? aren't there any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ignored" message will be fixed with: `cd  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ && rm rethinkdb.list.save.*`. Mind that a remove is permanent but also that "ignored" is not a fatal error: the system will continue.

> E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
> E: The list of sources could not be read.

... is fatal though. Use an editor and check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list` and fix the error. OR remove the file (as it refers to xenial = 16.04) with ...

`cd  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ && rm signal-xenial.list`

Comment: Thank you so much, the problem is fixed using the second proposed method, (deleting the problematic file)

Comment: Why `cd`? Just delete the files: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rethinkdb.list.save.*` and `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list`.

Comment: old habit @terdon :=)